# Node.js + bluebird + JSON. JSON is not valid after modification

Tags: json, node.js, bluebird

Trying to get [API](http://www.pathofexile.com/developer/docs/api) data. 
I have problem with creating valid JSON after modification.

Data should looks like this: [{"1"},{"2"},{"3"}, ... ,{201},{202},{203}, ...]

but now: [{"1"},{"2"},{"3"}, ...],[{"201"},{"202"},{"203"}, ...]

Where is my mistake?

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var request = require('bluebird').promisifyAll(require('request'));
var fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs'));
var ladders = {"hardcore":"hardcore", "standard":"standard"};

function getJSONsync(urls) {
    var ladder = [];
    Promise.map(urls, function(url) {
        return request
            .getAsync(url)
            .spread(function (res, body) {
                if (res.statusCode != 200) {
                    throw new Error('Unsuccessful attempt. Code: '+ res.statusCode);
                }
                return JSON.stringify(ladder.concat(JSON.parse(body).entries), "", 4);
            })
            .catch(console.error);
    },{ concurrency: 10 })
    .then(function(arr) {
        fs.writeFileAsync('file.json', arr);
    })
}

function setUrls(ladderName, offset, limit) {
    var arr = [];

    while(offset < 15000 ) {
        arr.push('http://api.pathofexile.com/ladders/'+ladderName+'?offset='+offset+'&limit='+limit);
        offset = offset + 200;
    }

    return arr;
}

getJSONsync(setUrls(ladders.hardcore, 0, 200));
```

Thx for help.
Sorry for my Eng.

Finally:

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var request = require('bluebird').promisifyAll(require('request'));
var fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs'));

var ladders = {"hardcore":"hardcore","standard":"standard"};

function getJSONsync(urls) {
  Promise.map(urls, function(url) {
    return request
      .getAsync(url)
      .spread(function (res, body) {
        if (res.statusCode != 200) {
          throw new Error('Unsuccessful attempt. Code: '+ res.statusCode);
        }
        return JSON.parse(body).entries;
      })
      .catch(console.error);
  },{ concurrency: 10 })
  .reduce(function(a, b) { return a.concat(b) })
  .then(function(arr) {
    fs.writeFileAsync('file.json', JSON.stringify(arr, "", 4));
    console.log(arr.length);
  })
}

function setUrls(ladder, offset, limit) {
    var arr = [];

    while(offset < 15000 ) {
        arr.push('http://api.pathofexile.com/ladders/'+ladder+'?offset='+offset+'&limit='+limit);
        offset = offset + 200;
    }

    return arr;
}

getJSONsync(setUrls(ladders.hardcore, 0, 200));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promise.map returns an array, so when you do `ladder.concat` you return another array, so it becomes `[[{"1"}], [{"1", "2"}]`

You should just remove concat:

`return JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(body).entries, "", 4);`

But if you want to use variable **ladder** you may `ladder.push(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(body).entries, "", 4))` and use it instead of **arr** returned variable

Comment: thx for your answer, now I know how to use .map :) I just add .reduce(function(a, b) {return a.concat(b)}) after .map and now I have valid json